# How to mock new return value each time the mocked object is called

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have multiple re.search in my code for which i am writing unit test i am trying to return new value each time i hit re.search.

snippet from py file:

```
for line in output.splitlines():
        match = re.search(r'(^.*-\d+\/\d+\/\d+)', line)
        if match:
            sp = match.group(1)
            if sp not in self.data['sess']:
                self.data['sess'][sp] = {}
            continue
```

Unit test case:

```
 @patch('re.search')
 def test_get_sess(selfpatch1):
    match = Values()
    match.group = Mock()
    match.group.side_effect = ['ms','qr', 'uv']
    patch2.return_value = match
    options = {'ss': "ss1" }
    s.get_sess(**options)
```

I am seeing StopIteration exception on execution of above code.

Please let me know how to solve the issue

Comment: Can you post the Traceback?

Comment: is this wat you are looking for ?

Comment: (Pdb) traceback.print_stack()
  File "/usr/local/python-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/python-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/python-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/pdb.py", line 1688, in <module>
    pdb.main()
  File "/usr/local/python-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/pdb.py", line 1661, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/local/python-3.4.5/lib/python3.4/pdb.py", line 1542, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)

Comment: Nope, you said you were getting a StopIteration Exception - Can you post the Traceback of that?